# How to make a content div stretch from a header div to a footer div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap's 'sticky footer' CSS to ensure my footer appears at the bottom of my page. How can I make my content (the blue div in the example) stretch all the way down to the footer (the yellow div in the example)? I've tried making `.content` 100% height but that has no effect.

**My CSS**

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.content {
  height: 100%;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

**My HTML**

```
<body>
<div class="header">This is my header</div>
<div class="content">This is my content</div>
<div class="footer">This is my footer</div>
</body>
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/pjktqnmo/1/

**Ref:** http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/sticky-footer-navbar.css

**Update:** My header contains my page title so the height of the header varies from page to page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a solution with no `position` property being used.

see snippet below:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    color:grey;
}
.header {
    background-color:red;
}
.content {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -60px; /* equal to footer height */
    background-color:blue
}
.content:after {
    content:"";
    display: block;
}
.footer, .content:after {
    height: 60px;
}
.footer {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="header">This is my header</div>
    <div class="content">This is my content</div>
    <div class="footer">This is my footer</div>
</body>
```

More info here: [**sticky footer**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/)

**UPDATED ANSWER** *Based on a Discussion with OP, where OP stated that **doesn't** want to have a Vertical ScrollBar, therefore here is a solution below:*

What I did? Make your div `.header` child of div `.content`, with 0 changes on CSS regarding my 1st snippet above.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    color:grey;
}
.header {
    background-color:red;
}
.content {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -60px; /* equal to footer height */
    background-color:blue
}
.content:after {
    content:"";
    display: block;
}
.footer, .content:after {
    height: 60px;
}
.footer {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="header">This is my header</div>
  This is my content
</div>
<div class="footer">This is my footer</div>
```

Comment: Neat solution, but this results in a vertical scroll bar showing?

Comment: Yeah I get you but this is showing a v-scroll bar even with hardly any content.

Comment: sorry, I've edited my comment a little bit before you reply me. So you don't want a scrollbar? is that it?

Comment: I do want a v-scroll bar _but_ only when there is enough content to warrant one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63618/discussion-between-dippas-and-henrywright).

Answer (score 0):

If your header is 30px tall, and your footer is 60px tall, this should work for the content:

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 31px;
bottom: 61px;
```

Comment: Sometimes my header can be more than 30px, depending on the title of the page. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 0):

Set the height like this:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.content {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pjktqnmo/6/

Comment: Problem then is you're left with a vertical scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

It's working pretty well with javascript.
It also allows you to have to good height when user changes window dimensions.

Call this on page load and when user changes the window dimension:

```
$('.content').css('height',$(document).height() - ($('.header').height() + $('.footer').height() + `MARGIN TOP OR PADDING`) - $('.contact').height());
```

Comment: Any idea how to make this work without JavaScript? unfortunately, I need to cater for the 0.000001% that have it disabled

Comment: Not sure if you need to keep `position relative`on HTML element, but here... http://jsfiddle.net/pjktqnmo/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a table instead as a container for your page.  Make sure that your `<html>`, `<body>`, and `<table>` elements have their width and height at 100%.

Make three rows in your table and put your header, content, and footer into each row, then make the content row 100% height so it will take up the rest of the page space.

Lastly, remove the spacing between the table cells

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.header {
  background-color: green;
}
.content {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: cyan;
}
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}
td {
  padding: 0px;
}
.contentCell {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="header">This is my header</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="contentCell">
      <td>
        <div class="content">This is my content</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="footer">This is my footer</div>
      </td>
    <tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: also has a v-scrollbar and OP only wants that when it is needed.

Comment: fixed, the body had a margin on it.

Comment: I'm wondering, are tables frowned upon when used for layout? or was that a thing of the past?